# problemas ao fazer update em uma tabela

Tags: php, ajax

sou iniciante em php.
alguém sabe por que não está funcionando?
Ele faz o update corretamente de valores inteiros, mas se for uma string de letras não funciona

**html** Ele vai digitar aqui uma url pra fazer o update

```
<input type="text" id="url_video">
```

**salva.php**

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","database_name");

$resultado = mysqli_query($con,"Select * from video");

    echo "<table class='table'>".
        "<thead>".
             "<tr>".
                "<td>ID</td>".
                "<td>url_video</td>".
             "</tr>".
        "</thead><tbody>";
while($valor = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
    echo "<tr>".
            "<td>".$valor['ID']."</td>".
            "<td>".$valor['url_video']."</td>".
            "<td><input type='button' value='Update' class='btn-update' data-id='".$valor['ID']."'>"."</td>".
         "</tr>";
}
echo "</tbody></table>";
```

**ajax** Eu mando a string digitada (url) e passo o id da coluna selecionada.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-update').click(function(){
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var string = $('#url_video').val();
        $.ajax({
            url: "tabelaUpdate.php",
            data: { 'idDeUpdate' : id,
                    'url_video' : string
                  },
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            success: function(response){
                $('#result').html(response); 
            }
        })
    });
});
```

**php** tabelaUpdate.php

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "database_name");
$id = $_POST['idDeUpdate'];
$string_url = $_POST['url_video'];


mysqli_query($con,"Update video SET url_video=$string_url WHERE ID=$id");
echo "ID -> ".$id." URL -> ".$string_url;
```

Comment: Só de curiosidade, por que você está usando supressão (@) no `mysql_connect`?

Comment: se eu não colocar, aparece essa mensagem->  Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: E não é melhor consertar do que esconder o alerta? Sugestão: aproveite que você está montando a aplicação e já troque isso por mysqli, em vez de ter que refazer tudo quando removerem essa função do PHP. (inclusive por que hoje você está correndo um risco de injection nesse AJAX, pela maneira que faz o update).

Comment: Fiz algumas alterações no código usando mysqli.

Comment: É bom que vc tenha posto o salva.php também. Pode ajudar alguém a achar o problema. Isso aqui me parece problemático: `var string = $('#url_video').val();`, vai sempre pegar o 1o URL, não?

Comment: Antes de mais nada, conecte no banco (Serve um cliente tipo o HeidiSQL) e confira se a coluna `url_video` está como `varchar`. Se não estiver, mude pra `varchar` que deve resolver. Se estiver poste o esquema da tabela que a gente replica mais certinho. :D

Comment: consegui resolver!  mysqli_query($con,"Update video SET url_video='$string_url' WHERE ID=$id"); faltou as aspas simples

Comment: @JoseMaximilian vc testou com mais de um valor pra ter certeza que o 2o video tb funciona?

Comment: funcionou, só usei uma caixa de texto pra testar mesmo. ou seja, ele digita a url e depois vai apertar um dos botões de update. mais pra frente eu coloco um input text dentro do loop pra fazer o update.

Comment: Isso, faça o teste com mais de um, pois acho que vai dar diferença entre o `$('#url_video').val();` e o `$(this).data('urlvideo');` que eu pus na resposta. Se faltar algo, avise, pois eu fiz a resposta sem ter como testar aqui pro seu caso específico. Posso ter cometido algum erro de sintaxe.

Comment: você poderia me dar umas dicas? eu mandei imprimir um input do tipo text dentro do loop do while: `"<td><input type='text' value='".$valor['url_video']."'  style='width: 400px;' id='url-video'></td>".` , dentro desse input é impresso  a `url do vídeo`, ao clicar no btn de update, eu mando ele atualizar o campo de input selecionado `var string = $('#url-video').val();`  o problema é que ele só atualiza a primeira coluna `url_video`, já os demais é feito apenas uma copia dessa primeira pros demais campos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eu sugeriria trocar esta linha:

```
"<td><input type='button' value='Update' class='btn-update' data-id='".$valor['ID']."'>"."</td>"
```

por esta:

```
"<td><input type='button' value='Update' class='btn-update' data-id='".$valor['ID']."' data-urlvideo='".$valor['url_video']."'>"."</td>"
```

E no JS pegar os dois parâmetros usando `.data`:

```
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var string = $(this).data('urlvideo');
```

Cabe também, como sugerido pelo @Fernando, checar se a tabela do DB está com o tipo correto no campo `url_video`, que deve ser textual, como `char` ou `varchar`.

Para completar, eu trocaria esta linha por "bind": em vez de usar concatenação de strings (assim você resolve o problema das aspas faltando, e se protege de injection):

Substituir:

```
mysqli_query($con,"Update video SET url_video=$string_url WHERE ID=$id");
```

Por:

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con,"Update video SET url_video=? WHERE ID=?");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'si', $string_url, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Assim estará minimizando a chance de **[SQL Injection](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3864)**.